# How to exclude a specific dependency injected from external library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

So I have a class `JarComponent` in an external library that's configured to inject some of its child components by default

```
@Component
public class JarComponent {
   @Autowired(required=false)
   DependencyI dependencyI;
   @Autowired(required=false)
   DependencyII dependencyII;
   @Autowired(required=false)
   DependencyIII dependencyIII;
   ... // a lot of other dependencies
   @Autowired(required=false)
   DependencyVIII dependencyVIII;
}
```

And because this is from Jar I have no access to modify this class, when I registered the `JarComponent` in my application,

```
@Component
public class MyAppComponent {
  @Autowired
  JarComponent jarComponent;
}

// MyAppComponent <- JarComponent <- (dependencyI, dependencyII, dependencyIII, ..., dependencyVIII)
```

all associated dependencies will also be registered automatically. However, one of the dependencies - `dependencyII` might break my application so I'd like to exclude it specifically, at the same time I can continue keeping other dependencies that are brought from `JarComponent` ,  here is the expectation

The workaround for now is I have to explicitly not inject `JarComponent` but inject all its child components except `dependencyII`,

```
@Component
public class AppComponent {
  // @Autowired
  // JarComponent jarComponent;

  @Autowired
  DependencyI dependencyI;
  @Autowired
  DependencyIII dependencyIII;
  ...,
  @Autowired
  DependencyVIII dependencyVIII;
}
```

which is kinda ugly...is there any other elegant way to do that?